# How to solve $ \lfloor x+2\rfloor-1=0 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need some help to solve the next equation:
$$
\lfloor x+2\rfloor-1=0
$$
Where $\lfloor .\rfloor$ is the floor function.

What I've tried:
$$
\lfloor x+2\rfloor-1=0 \Rightarrow \lfloor x\rfloor=-1 \Rightarrow x \in(0,1)
$$

Is that right??

Comment: It's correct up to $\lfloor x\rfloor=-1$.  After that, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
[x+2]-1=0 &\iff [x+2]=1 \\
& \iff 1 \leqq x+2 < 2\\
& \iff -1 \leqq x <0.
\end{align}

You can see the graph of $y=[x+2]$ with wolfram alpha.

If you see the point of $y=1$, you will be able to realize the range of $x$.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%28x%2B2%29&lang=ja